# PKPassLibrary doesn't work on device

Tags: passbook

I'm working on passbook usage and everything seems to be OK on device, but, even if I install a provisioning profile with passbook activated, nothing is detected under entilement part in XCode 4.5.

Is there a format to respect in pass type identifier to be able to access a pass in the application, or is there another way that I ignore.

Comment: Thanks for yor help... I found by myself

Comment: Can you post an answer so that others may be able to benefit from the solution as well?

Answer (score 0):

You can access only passes which has same pass identifier which you are using in your application.

```
PKPassLibrary passes
```

This method only get passes which has same pass type ID.

Each and every info relates PassBook : https://developer.apple.com/passbook/